# Difference between the length of id and class objects

Tags: javascript, html

This J fiddle utilizes getElementsByClassName

http://jsfiddle.net/YZTpn/

This j fiddle uses getElementByID

http://jsfiddle.net/9Fa89/

```
<script>
```

when I print out the length of the var "x".... the length is different for the class and id versions. The id version actually spits out the correct value which is 4... rather than 1.... which class spits out.

Comment: for length after getElementById, it looks like it is giving the length of it's children. for getElementbyClassName is actually giving a collection of the matched elements and so using length on it gives the length of matched items.

Comment: Who thinks it's a good idea to close this? Or downvote? It's a great question!

Comment: Good Doubt. I appreciate this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**document.getElementsByClassName**

> Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names. When
> called on the document object, the complete document is searched,
> including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName on
> any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the
> specified root element with the given class names.

[Read More..](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

**document.getElementById**

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

[Read More](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

**Element.length**

> length returns the number of items in a NodeList.

[Read More](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.length)

now in your jsfiddles..

`document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect" ).length` is 1.. why?
document.getElementsByClassName .. returns a set of elements.. i.e an Array.. and as there are only one element with class name "mySelect" the length of the array wil be 1

---

`document.getElementById("mySelect" ).length` is 4. why?
document.getElementById returns a refrence to the element and as there are four elements in the nodelist of the element.. (in your case 4 `<option>` s) so Element.length will return 4..

Answer (score 3):

GetElementsByClassName is returning a set of length 1, so you need to get the first element of the set and ask for its length.

GetElementById gives you the element directly, and you then ask for its length, which gives you the number of children.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you are performing `getElementByID`, you are being returned a single DOM element which has that ID. When you are performing `getElementsByClassName`, you are being returned a `NodeList` which contains any DOM element that has that class name assigned to it. So, when you are doing x.length with `getElementsByClassName` you are actually doing NodeList.length which is 1.

What I think you actually want is `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect")[0].length;` or some variation of that.

Answer (score 0):

maybey you could try this instead:

```
<script>
function displayResult()
{
var x=document.getElementsByName('Select');
alert(x.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select Class="mySelect">
    <option value="apple" name="Select">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange" name="Select">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple" name="Select">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana" name="Select">Banana</option>
 </select>
```

Display value